# In Scala, what's the difference between declaring a top-level trait to be private or package private?

Tags: scala

In Scala, what's the difference between declaring a non-nested trait to be private or package private. I.e., what's the difference between

```
private MyTrait { ... }
```

and

```
private[enclosingpackage] MyTrait { ... }
```

I know that there ***is*** a difference because I can get certain compilation errors to go away if I add the package qualifier. E.g., these two compilation errors will go away if I add the package qualifier to the definition of the `Service` trait:

```
[error] /Users/dalan/s/local/eclipse/jeep/runcible/src/main/scala/
org/gaffa/gpp/runcible/httpserver/HttpServer.scala:146:
private trait Service escapes its defining scope as part of type
org.gaffa.gpp.runcible.httpserver.Service
[error] object HttpServer extends App with Service {
[error]                                    ^
[error] /Users/dalan/s/local/eclipse/jeep/runcible/src/main/scala/org/
gaffa/gpp/runcible/httpserver/HttpServer.scala:156: not found: value routes
[error] Http().bindAndHandle(routes, config.getString("http.interface"),   
config.getInt("http.port"))
[error]                      ^
[error] two errors found
```

The `routes` val that is being complained about in one of the error messages is in the `Service` trait, which is being "extended" by the `HttpServer` singleton `object`.

Thanks for your help!

P.S. All the code in question is in the same file, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Take a look at this old discussion http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at the old discussion article referred by Chris: the qualified private[foo] and the normal private are acting on different levels.

The qualified private[foo] is checked by the Scala compiler and it's giving you access to the resource as long as you belong to the same package. That's why it compiles in the case you are asking here.

Thus, the normal private is a Java regular private instruction that seals the resource to only be used by the resource itself.

None of them is better than the other, of course, it depends on the scope of protection you want to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. It must lead to compile error in both cases, because in both cases "`trait Service escapes its defining scope`", but with **qualified private** compiler forgets to do this check.

Seemed that you have met this bug: [SI-4323](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4323)